# Why two times copy constructor and destructor gets called in following code

Tags: c++

I following program, While creating an obj, default constructor gets called but two times copy constructor and two destructor gets called. I am not able to understand why this is happening ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class sam
{
public :
    sam()
    { 
        cout<<"\n Default Constuctor"; 
    }
    sam(int a)
    {
        cout<<"\n Parameterised Constuctor";
    }
    sam(const sam &obj)
    {
        cout<<"\n Copy Constuctor";
    }

    sam & operator = (const sam &obj)
    {
        cout<<"\n Overloaded assignment operator";
    }

    ~sam()
    {
        cout<<"\n destructor";
    }
};


void fun()
{
    try
    {
        sam obj;
        throw obj;
    }
    catch(char *ptr)
    {
        cout<<"\n Catch block";
    }
    catch(sam ex)
    {
        cout<<"\n fun ";
    }
}

int main()
{

    fun();
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is :

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception and Copy Constructor : C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432959/exception-and-copy-constructor-c)

Answer (score 1):

You are throwing `obj` and catching it *by value* as `ex`. Copies happen when you do that and those temporary objects get destroyed as well.

General rule of thumb regarding catching exceptions; always catch by const reference (`const& foo`) unless you have a special reason not to do so.