# Exception guarantees and pass by value

Tags: c++

I've come across this issue in several contexts recently, and some of the opinions expressed on it have surprised me. Here's a first simple example:

```
void f(std::vector<double> x) {};
```

The question is: is it acceptable to document or describe `f` as offering the no throw guarantee? Similarly, I suspect that since the exception is not generated from f's body, using `noexcept` is technically kosher. But should one mark it `noexcept`? An example would be, for instance, an optimized version of `set` that somehow finds it useful to add the requirement that the templated comparator must not throw. It detects this at compile time using a static assert and causes an error. Yet, someone could write a comparator for vectors that takes by value, and mark it noexcept, and use it with this version of `set`. Is it then the container author's fault if this causes poor behavior? Or the person who marked the comparator noexcept?

To take another example that involves another type of exception guarantee, consider:

```
void g(std::vector<double> x, std::unique_ptr<int> y);
```

Can this function ever offer the strong guarantee?

```
std::vector<double> p{1.0, 2.0};
auto q = std::make_unique<int>(0);
bool func_successful = true;

try {
  g(p, std::move(q));
}
catch (...) {
  func_successful = false;
}

if (!func_successful)
  assert(q);
```

I would argue that if the assertion can ever fail, then g does not offer the strong guarantee, because `q` was not empty immediately prior to calling g (remembering that `std::move` doesn't actually move anything). And it can fail: order of parameter evaluation is unspecified, so y may be constructed first emptying q, followed by x being constructed and throwing. Is the function still responsible for this even though it does not technically occur in the body, but in the act of calling the function?

Edit: I was going to mention that Herb Sutter talks about this issue here: https://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64?t=1h11m56s. He says that marking such a function noexcept is "problematic"; I'm hoping for a more detailed response.

Comment: I can't find text right now, but surely the function exception specification only begins once the function body is entered. The caller can control the behaviour of parameters, e.g. I'd expect `noexcept(f(vec))` to be `false` but `noexcept(f(std::move(vec)))` to be `true`.

Comment: The `set` example is a bad one. You'd test something like `noexcept(comp(a, b))` and that takes the copying into account already.

Comment: @M.M I agree. The question is whether it spiritually should be marked noexcept, or if this is just exploiting a sort of edge case. The caller can control parameter behavior, but a noexcept function should never be thrown with any arguments it can be called with, right?

Comment: @T.C. That's a good point. I don't have a better example handy, I'm definitely all ears though. I think though one can see that a better example may exist.

Comment: I don't think that's what it means . `noexcept` is still useful for `f` because the calling code can still optimize based on that, even when the calling code is prepared to catch exceptions that occur when constructing the parameters. (it knows there won't be any other exceptions)

Comment: @M.M Your point is well taken, it just seems to seriously take the teeth out of your exception guarantees when a user always has to search to see whether every type has an & or two on it, and if some of the types are unfamiliar, start recursing down their copy constructors.

Comment: It is what it is... the same sort of problem occurs if you want to know whether `T a; a = b;` can throw or not for some unfamiliar `T`, writing a noexcept function body is more than just a matter of writing a series of noexcept function calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is: is it acceptable to document or describe f as offering the no throw guarantee?

The C++ standard does not believe that it is. Consider its treatment of nothrow when applied to assignment.

`is_assignable` is true if, for `T` and `U`, this expression is valid: `std::declval<T>() = std::declval<U>()`. `is_nothrow_assignable` is true if *that expression* is noexcept, in its entirety. The same goes for copy/move assignment (obviously with the same type).

The initialization of the `operator=` parameter is part of the expression. And therefore, if that initialization can throw, then the assignment is not nothrow. There's a [working group paper discussing this matter in some depth](http://wg21.link/P0129) (primarily around move assignment).

The question of whether you should mark this function `noexcept` is a separate matter. But a function simply being `noexcept` should not be confused with the belief that parts of a function call expression will never throw.

My personal feeling on the matter is that you shouldn't be marking random functions `noexcept` to begin with. You should use them with special member functions and other very specific places where you have an explicit *need* to use it. That is, it should be something more than a semantic marker for a user. Use `noexcept` when someone is actually going to do metaprogramming and choose to call or not call that function based on whether it is `noexcept`.

Comment: I agree with not marking random functions no except, but consider the example of a unified assignment operator, one of the examples that led me to this question. I argue that unified assignment operators are bad; if you have a separate assignment operator for move and copy, you can mark the former but not the latter noexcept. However, others argued that it was acceptable to mark the unified assignment operator noexcept. What is your feeling on this?

Comment: Ah, I see your response on the other thread, never mind. Excellent answer, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The standard (5.2.2 Function call [expr.call] §4) says that parameter initialization and destruction take place in the context of the calling function. So yes, it *is* technically kosher to declare `f` as `noexcept`.

It does make sense though, even if it is counter-intuitive at first. `f` could be called with an rvalue, in which case the move-ctor would be used to initialize the parameter, so even the whole construct of calling the function (including parameter setup and tear-down) would still be `noexcept`. Or `f` could be called with an empty vector, in which case the whole construct would still *effectively* be `noexcept` - at least with what I would consider "reasonable" library implementations.

Also consider functions with const-ref parameters:

```
void x(std::string const&) noexcept {}

void y() noexcept
{
    x("foo");
}
```

`x` is `noexcept` allright. The call in `y` however is not, because it includes a (possibly throwing) implicit conversion. So if declaring `f` as `noexcept` was bad style, wouldn't the same have to be said for `x`?

So I think C++ programmers should do one of two things: not use and not rely on `noexcept` specifications, or internalize the rules and always be weary of what they're doing at the call site.

---

Regarding the second question (strong guarantee)...
I'd say that a function can never make claims about the *arguments* it's called with. Also it can never make claims about what happens to its would-be *parameters* if it's never actually called.

If the strong guarantee that you have in mind includes such claims, then I would agree that the function can not give that kind of strong guarantee.

Although I wouldn't necessarily agree that the strong guarantee - for a function with a signature like this - should include such claims.
What I *would* say is: *if* such claims are necessary for the strong guarantee to make any kind of practical sense, then the function should not use by-value parameters.

OTOH, if such claims are not necessary for the strong guarantee to make practical sense, then I see no reason why I would "forbid" it. E.g.

```
void StrongAppendAll(std::vector<T>& a, std::vector<T> b);
```

IMO the "natural" strong guarantee for this function would be that *it either appends all elements in `b` to `a`, or, in case an exception is thrown, leaves `a` unchanged*. I would never assume that the guarantee includes any claim about what happens to `b`. Even less any claim about what happens to whatever argument was used to initialize `b`.

Comment: How about just not marking random functions `noexcept`?

Comment: Yes, how about it? I'm not advertising marking everything and it's mother `noexcept`. I'm just saying I don't see a really good reason against declaring such functions `noexcept`. Assuming that there's a good reason `for` doing so.

Comment: @PaulGroke I feel this makes very strong points for noexcept cases and has definitely changed how I feel about those to some degree. I do still think though that in the second example, I would be annoyed if someone documented g as having the strong guarantee. IMHO if you want to do the strong guarantee, there's no real excuse not to just take everything by reference.

Comment: @Nir Friedman: The "strong guarantee" part of your question was much harder for me to put into words, which is why I left it out at first. And I'm not sure that I did a very good job of it now, even after spending quite some time on it :)

Comment: @Paul Groke I think it's an insightful answer, thanks for taking the time.