# Is x = std::move(x) undefined?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

Let `x` be a variable of some type that has been previously initialized. Is the following line:

```
x = std::move(x)
```

undefined? Where is this in the standard and what does it say about it?

Comment: It is (user) implementation defined, it has the same issues as the traditional assignment operator.

Comment: What's the sense of it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ uuum, what? This is an assignment, not initialization… clearly `x` needs to be declared first, and it doesn't *have to* be declared without initialization. So assuming OP meant to move an initialized object onto itself, if this triggers UB, it's not the lack of initialization that does so. Moving means that the object "is in an unspecified but valid state" (that's how the standard formulates it).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You can assume `x` has been initialized somewhere else. Editing to make that clear.

Comment: It isn't a "race condition". Is there a name for such read write conflict in one thread?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322174/move-assignment-operator-and-if-this-rhs/   , this question is intimitely tied with the question of whether a class's move-assignment operator should cater to self-assignment.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

No, this is not undefined behavior, it is going to be implementation defined behavior, it will depend on how move assignment is implemented.

Relevant to this is [LWG issue 2468: Self-move-assignment of library types](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2468) , note this is an active issue and does not have an official proposal so this should be considered indicative rather than definitive, but it does point out the sections that are involved for the standard library and points out they currently conflict. It says:

> Suppose we write
>
> ```
> vector<string> v{"a", "b", "c", "d"};
> v = move(v);
> ```
>
> What should be the state of v be? The standard doesn't say anything
>   specific about self-move-assignment. There's relevant text in several
>   parts of the standard, and it's not clear how to reconcile them.
>
> [...]
>
> It's not clear from the text how to put these pieces together, because it's not clear which one takes precedence. Maybe 17.6.4.9 [res.on.arguments] wins (it imposes an implicit precondition that isn't mentioned in the MoveAssignable requirements, so v = move(v) is undefined), or maybe 23.2.1 [container.requirements.general] wins (it explicitly gives additional guarantees for Container::operator= beyond what's guaranteed for library functions in general, so v = move(v) is a no-op), or maybe something else.
>
> On the existing implementations that I checked, for what it's worth, v = move(v) appeared to clear the vector; it didn't leave the vector unchanged and it didn't cause a crash.

and proposes:

> Informally: change the MoveAssignable and Container requirements tables (and any other requirements tables that mention move assignment, if any) to make it explicit that x = move(x) is defined behavior and it leaves x in a valid but unspecified state. That's probably not what the standard says today, but it's probably what we intended and it's consistent with what we've told users and with what implementations actually do.

Note, for built-in types this is basically a copy, we can see from draft C++14 standard section `5.17` *[expr.ass]*:

> In simple assignment (=), the value of the expression replaces that of the object referred to by the left
>   operand.

which is different than the case for classes, where `5.17` says:

> If the left operand is of class type, the class shall be complete. Assignment to objects of a class is defined
>   by the copy/move assignment operator (12.8, 13.5.3).

Note, clang has a [self move warning](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20150105/120983.html):

> Log:
>   Add a new warning, -Wself-move, to Clang.
>
> -Wself-move is similiar to -Wself-assign.  This warning is triggered when
>   a value is attempted to be moved to itself.  See r221008 for a bug that
>   would have been caught with this warning.

Comment: I wouldn't call the proposal in LWG 2468 anything more than that; it's just a proposal by the issue submitter and doesn't necessarily reflect the LWG's view. Under the standard as written, I would argue that the restriction in [res.on.arguments] renders self-move-assignment UB for standard library types.

Comment: @T.C. that is fair point, I should have been more careful with how I worded that. I updated with more careful wording.

Comment: "Just a proposal" is a slight understatement; Matt Austern is one of the most respected LWG members. I'm not 100% sure if he's still the LWG chair but he's been that for a _very_ long time.

Comment: @MSalters: That's an appeal to popularity or something. Regardless, it _is_ just a proposal!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It would be "appeal to authority"  which happens to be a valid appeal when the authority at hand is in fact the rule-making authority.

Comment: @MSalters: It's still not a rule until everybody else agrees it's a rule and the proposal is accepted as a rule and becomes part of an International Standard. That's the entire purpose of this process! I _would_ go with you so far as to say that it's likely this particular proposal, given the identity of its submitter, does indeed reflect general LWG view. (And no, being respected isn't "authority"! Being chair could be though.)

Comment: The clang link is broken.

Comment: [2468 moved to defect](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2468) also [active issue 2839 relevant](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2839)

Comment: There is a new issues on this [LWG 2839: Self-move-assignment of library types, again](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2839)

Comment: @becko I fixed it

Answer (score 13):

It will call `X::operator = (X&&)`, so it is up to the implementation to manage this case (as it is done for `X::operator = (const X&)`)

Comment: And what if I use the copy-swap idiom, where I define a unified assignment operator (capturing by value instead of const ref)? In this case I cannot check for self-assignment inside the operator implementation.

Answer (score 11):

All that does is call `X::operator=(X&&)` (with an lvalue qualified "`*this`").

On primitive types, `std::move` does little of interest, and does not interact with `=` at all.  So this only applies to objects of class type.

Now, for a type within `std` (or generated by one of its templates), objects `move`d from tend to be left in an unspecified (yet valid) state.  This is not undefined behavior, but it isn't useful behavior.

The semantics of a each given `X::operator=(X&&)` would have to be examined, examining every type within `std` would be "too broad" for a stack overflow answer.  They even may contradict themselves.

In general, when `move`ing from an object, you are communicating to the consumer that "you don't care what state the object is in afterwards".  The use of a `x = std::move(x)` is thus impolite, as you (usually) *do* care what state `x` is in after the operation completes (as you are assigning to it).  You are using the same object as both an lvalue and an rvalue within the same operation, and that is not good a practice.

An interesting exception is the default `std::swap`, which goes something like this:

```
template<class T>
void swap(T& lhs, T& rhs) {
  T tmp = std::move(lhs);
  lhs = std::move(rhs);
  rhs = std::move(tmp);
}
```

the middle line, `lhs = std::move(rhs)`, does an `x = std::move(x)` if you call swap twice on the same object.

Note, however, that we do not care what state `x` is in after this line is completed; we have already stored the state of `x` in `tmp`, and we will restore it on the next line.

Comment: The library thinks about `std::move(x)`, or rvalues in general, as "nobody else aliases this". I've found that a useful viewpoint.

Comment: *"The use of a `x = std::move(x)` is thus impolite"* yet it happens with the generic `swap`, possibly during some algorithm.

Comment: @dyp `template<class T> void swap( T& lhs, T& rhs ) { T tmp = std::move(lhs); lhs = std::move(rhs); rhs = std::move(tmp); }` does do an `x=std::move(x);`  It does so in a context where *it does not matter what state `x` is in afterwards* however, as its state is overwritten on the next line (and "saved" on the previous line)

Comment: Yes, agreed, but if self-swap is guaranteed to work, then self-move-assignment must be safe, not undefined (wrt the OP). (Essentially, this implies move-assignment has no preconditions / requirements on the argument. IMHO this and the postcondition you've mentioned are both important.)