# Invalid use of move?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, move

Could somebody give me hints on why this code doesn't output anything? 
I'm assuming it has something to do with the move line...

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm> 

using namespace std; 

int main(){ 
vector<int> v{66,79,154,24,76,13,7}; 

v = move(v); 
for(auto i: v) 
cout << i << " "; 
}
```

Update: So I added system("pause"); to help myself. Whether I need it or not is not what I'm focusing on. When I ran the code again in Visual Studio 2013, it worked. However, when I ran it through Ideone using C++14, it didn't output anything. Slightly confused now.

[image: Visual Studio 2013]
[image: Ideone]

Comment: `v = move(v);` is undefined behavior?

Comment: what is the compiler you are using?

Comment: Currently using Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't think vector or any other container handles a move to itself so the operation just frees the lhs then moves the already freed hrs.

Comment: It is implementation defined, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/31547466/72178.

Comment: You never flush std::cout. To do so, add `std::cout << std::endl;` at the end of main().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will have to say it's unreproducible.

I used my Visual studio 2015 Update 3 and the output is normal :

> 66 79 154 24 76 13 7

Moreover, under VC++ implementation there is no problem moving the vector to itself:

```
_Myt& operator=(_Myt&& _Right)
        {   // assign by moving _Right
        if (this != &_Right)
            {   // different, assign it
            clear();

        if (_Alty::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value
            && this->get_allocator() != _Right.get_allocator())
            {   // assign vector, dumping proxy
            this->_Free_proxy();
            this->_Myvec = _STD move(_Right._Myvec);
            this->_Alloc_proxy();
            }
        else
            this->_Myvec = _STD move(_Right._Myvec);


        this->_Mysize = _Right._Mysize;
        _Right._Mysize = 0;
        }
    return (*this);
    }
```

as you can see from the condition `this != &_Right`, the moving will only happen if you **are not** moving a vector to itself.

EDIT:

apparently the compiler which is used to compile "C++14" on Ideone (GCC?) decides to not check self-move assignment and decides to free the vector data. 
as we can see from [this little experiment](https://ideone.com/pzCeBy), after the move the vector size is 0. as said in other previous answers/comments, assigning a move to itself is implementation defined. I guess VC++ does the right thing in this case.

EDIT 2:

it appears that GCC really [doesn't check for self asignment.](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/1cb6c2eb3b8361d850be8e8270c597270a1a7967/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h#L1527) it moves the vector data into a temporary one, and takes `__x` data, which in that point is already empty. man, sometimes GCC behaves stupidly just for sake of false sense performance ( because cmp + jz are really going to slow your program down? please.)

Comment: Just tested it on Ideone since I'm currently using my phone and forgot to open a compiler app which I have. Tried this again and it produced no output. Did you change or add anything?

Comment: when you get back, paste a screeshot of you see + tell us the exact compiler + version. and no, I didn't change anything.

Comment: So based on your newest edit, I would assume that I should go based on what Visual Studio is showing me?

Comment: @N.O'Neil you should trust tests and QA only. never assume your code simply works.

Answer (score 4):

The standard library functions called with `xvalue` arguments may assume the argument is the only reference to the object; if it was constructed from an `lvalue` with `std::move`, no aliasing checks are made. In particular, this means that standard library move assignment operators do not have to perform self-assignment checks:

```
std::vector<int> v = {2, 3, 3};
v = std::move(v); // undefined behavior
```

For more detail please refer [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127455/what-does-the-standard-library-guarantee-about-self-move-assignment)