# C++ move a range by a non-negative displacement?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I was faced with a need to move a range of elements backward by a certain (possibly zero) displacement.  To illustrate, here is some code:

```
std::vector<int> arr[4] = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}};
std::move(arr + 2, arr + 4, arr + 2 - k); // k can be either 0, 1, or 2,
// depending on how far much I want to move the elements
```

This works as expected when `k` is nonzero, but fails when `k` is zero (I expect the move to become a no-op when k=0).

The following code, when compiled in GCC will cause `arr[2]` and `arr[3]` to lose all their elements:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr[4] = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}};
    std::move(arr + 2, arr + 4, arr + 2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) std::cout << arr[i].size() << ' '; // prints "1 1 0 0 "
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) says that `std::move`'s destination should not be in the range `[first, last)`, and my code has been in violation of this.

After some digging, I found that self move assignment (i.e. `x = std::move(x)`) [is not expected to be a no-op](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9322542/1021959), so that seems to be why I'm not allowed to do a no-op range `std::move`.

This issue would also happen if I want to move a range of elements *forward* by a certain (possibly zero) displacement.

To solve this problem, I could check explicitly that `k` is nonzero before moving.  But is this the idiomatic C++ way?

Comment: Couldn't you use [std::rotate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) for this?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes `std::rotate` would work. But that seems slower due to moving extra elements, as I don't actually need to do a 'rotation'.

Comment: Unless this is in a *very* hot code path I doubt it matters.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, such a check would be very typical. Even if x[i]=x[i+0]; were a no-op you would still want to skip the loop processing if possible and that's what the zero-displacement check would provide.